# wicked_pdf (1.1.0) , wkhtmltopdf-binary (0.12.3.1) (font size working differently on different enviroments)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Pdf font is being render smaller in the production compared to development. I checked stack overflow, but could not  get a precise reason for the issue.

development shows the font size  as we have given , compared the production renders it smaller than the development.

Below is the snippet for the font family.

```
body{
    font-family: Lato,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  }


.header-spec {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:25px;
  }
```

//how much ever i tried to increase the size(to 25px)in development,after deployment to production it shows the fontsize of 10px;

Comment: Do you have the exact same gems in both production and development ? (Only wicked-pdf and wkhtmltopdf-binary) When I updated wkhtmltopdf-binary it gave me a completely different PDF, I had to revert to original version

Comment: yes same gems in both production and development(for (Only wicked-pdf and wkhtmltopdf-binary).

Comment: I am pretty sure it is a gem issue. In my gemfile I have `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary-edge', '0.12.4.0'` `gem 'wicked_pdf', '1.1.0'` and for prod env `gem 'wkhtmltopdf-heroku', '2.12.4.0'` maybe you can try these. It will probably change again your font sizes, but then you can compare if it the samne in dev and prod. (and fix later the layout by adjusting CSS). See the documented probem with unconsistent font sizes : https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/3266

Comment: Oh by the way I work on Ubuntu, if you work in windows you may have to install the correct 0.12.4 binaries